# How to turn off logging from root loggers in imported modules in Python?

Tags: python, logging

If it was a named logger I could just do something like `logging.getLogger("name").setLevel(logging.WARNING)` so I don't get DEBUG messages from the module.

I could also just change the threshold of rootLogger for my application but I want to keep it at DEBUG since I'm interested in DEBUG messages from some other modules, just not this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the root logger by not providing a parameter to `getLogger`.

```
# set level on root logger
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Edit: since the comment clarified what the expected answer is. If the logs are not directly sent to the root logger, in which case they can't be prevented, they can be stopped from reaching the root logger by setting propagate to `false` on the logger they originate at.

Comment: As I noted in my question, I don't want to change the threshold for rootLogger for my application since I'm interested in DEBUG messages from some other modules.

Comment: @SaravananSetty added an edit that may help

Comment: If I understand correctly what the edit is saying is that we can change the logger on imported module to not propagate up? But what if I can't change the source of the imported module.

Comment: you can still change it by getting the logger by it's name. all loggers are accessible to every module

Comment: The module is using the rootLogger, not a named logger. So what would I even use as the "name" to get the logger?

Comment: There is only one global root logger, and you can get it by not using a name, as explained in the answer. But if the module is sending logs directly to the root logger, and you don't want to change the root loggers level, you can't stop those logs.

Comment: > if the module is sending logs directly to the root logger, and you don't want to change the root loggers level, you can't stop those logs. 

Yup, that's the case unfortunately.

Comment: Probably use a different module than, good libraries don't do that.